# cpp data types runtime overflow

Tags: c++

> Given a non-empty binary tree, find the maximum path sum.
>
> For this problem, a path is defined as any sequence of nodes from some starting node to any node in the tree along the parent-child connections. The path must contain at least one node and does not need to go through the root.
>
> ```
>   -10
>    / \
>   9  20
>     /  \
>    15   7
> ```
>
> ans = 42

I am beginner. Help with only cpp if possible I am very clear about logic. I  want to know what's wrong with my data type knowledge.

Below maxpathsum function must return int value i am using long long just to avoid to integer overflow and then typecasting it before returning final answer.

input : [1,2] (1 is parent of two) expected output : 3

actual output : every time garbage value on leetcode but sometimes gives correct output as 3 also I know its data type error. When I try to run it on visual studio or codeblocks, I am getting correct output as 3. What's wrong in below code?

```
long long int solve(TreeNode* root,long long int &res) {
    if (root == NULL)return INT_MIN;
    long long int left = solve(root->left, res);
    long long int right = solve(root->right, res);
    //cout << left + right;
    long long int temp = max(left, max(right, left + right)) + root->val;
    res = max(1LL*res, temp);
    res = max(1LL*res,1LL* root->val);
    return max(left + 1LL * root->val, max(right + 1LL * root->val, 1LL * root->val));
}
//below function must return int value 
// i am using long long just to avoid to integer overflow
int maxPathSum(TreeNode* root) {
    long long int res;
    if(root==NULL)return 0;
    if(root->left==NULL && root->right==NULL)return root->val;
    solve(root, res);
    int ans = (int)res;
    return ans;
}
```

Comment: You don't initialize `res` in the `maxPathSum` function.

Comment: Thank you very much  sir accepted @ChrisMM

Answer (score 0):

```
if (root == NULL)return INT_MIN;
```

Please use 0. This is a large negative number.

Comment: Are you sure? He's getting an overflow problem. Are you sure this isn't the cause?

Comment: @JosephLarson Given the use of `max()` in the question, `0` is the right return here not `INT_MIN`.